# How to download new uploaded files from s3 to ec2 everytime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an `s3` bucket which will receive new files throughout the day. I want to download these to my `ec2` instance everytime a new file is uploaded to the bucket.

I have read that its possible using `sqs` or `sns` or `lambda`. Which is the easiest of them all? I need the file to be downloaded as early as possible once it is uploaded into the bucket.

**EDIT**

I basically will be getting png images in the bucket every few seconds or minutes. Everytime a new image is uploaded, I want to download that on the instance which is already running. I will do some AI processing. As the images will keeep coming into the bucket, I want to constantly keep downloading it in the ec2 and process it as soon as possible.
This is my code in the Lambda function so far.

```
import boto3
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """Read file from s3 on trigger."""
    #print(event)
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    client = boto3.client("ec2")
    ssm = boto3.client("ssm")
    instanceid = "******"

    if event:
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        #print(file_obj)
        bucketname = str(file_obj["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
        print(bucketname)
        filename = str(file_obj["s3"]["object"]["key"])
        print(filename)
        
        response = ssm.send_command(
            InstanceIds=[instanceid],
            DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
            Parameters={
                "commands": [f"aws s3 cp {filename} ."]
            },  # replace command_to_be_executed with command
        )
        
  
        # fetching command id for the output
        command_id = response["Command"]["CommandId"]

        time.sleep(3)

        # fetching command output
        output = ssm.get_command_invocation(CommandId=command_id, InstanceId=instanceid)
        print(output)
    return
```

However I am getting the following error

```
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2021-12-01T14:11:30.781Z 88dbe51b-53d6-4c06-8c16-207698b3a936 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 88dbe51b-53d6-4c06-8c16-207698b3a936 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 88dbe51b-53d6-4c06-8c16-207698b3a936
REPORT RequestId: 88dbe51b-53d6-4c06-8c16-207698b3a936  Duration: 3003.58 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 87 MB  Init Duration: 314.81 ms    
2021-12-01T14:11:30.781Z 88dbe51b-53d6-4c06-8c16-207698b3a936 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

Request ID
88dbe51b-53d6-4c06-8c16-207698b3a936
```

When I remove all the lines related to ssm, it works fine. Is there any permission issue or is there any problem with the code?

**EDIT2**

My code is working but I dont see any output or change in my ec2 instance. I should be seeing an empty text file in the home directory but I dont see anything
Code

```
import boto3
import json
import time

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """Read file from s3 on trigger."""
    #print(event)
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    client = boto3.client("ec2")
    ssm = boto3.client("ssm")
    instanceid = "******"
    print("HI")
    if event:
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        #print(file_obj)
        bucketname = str(file_obj["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
        print(bucketname)
        filename = str(file_obj["s3"]["object"]["key"])
        print(filename)
        print("sending")
        try:
            response = ssm.send_command(
                InstanceIds=[instanceid],
                DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
                Parameters={
                    "commands": ["touch hi.txt"]
                },  # replace command_to_be_executed with command
            )
            # fetching command id for the output
            command_id = response["Command"]["CommandId"]

            time.sleep(3)

            # fetching command output
            output = ssm.get_command_invocation(CommandId=command_id, InstanceId=instanceid)
            print(output)
            
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            raise e
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about _why_ you want to download it every time? Will the file(s) be processed on the instance somehow? If so, how will your app know that a new file has arrived -- is it checking for files, or does it need to be 'triggered' somehow? Will you be keeping all historical files on the instance (which means you could use `aws s3 sync`), or will files be removed after being processed? Please Edit your question to provide these additional details so that we can offer appropriate advice.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have added the details of the problem now

Comment: As per @theherk's comments, your approach seems to be incorrect. Don't think of it as "copying files to EC2". Rather, think of it  as "whenever a new object appears in S3, I want to process it using code on the EC2 instance". That code can both download the file _and_ process the image. The best architectural method would be to have S3 send a message to an Amazon SQS queue, then your program on the EC2 instance would fetch a message, download the file, process the file, then delete the message from the SQS queue. This is scalable since SQS will act as a buffer of work to be done.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways. One would be to setup [s3 notifications to invoke a lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html). Then lambda function would use [SSM Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to execute AWS CLI S3 command on your instance to download the file from S3.

Comment: Im getting the following error in the lambda function when i run test the code
```
{
  "errorMessage": "2021-12-01T14:01:21.513Z c028410e-3a98-4041-b46d-b4756d3a04d4 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}
```

Comment: I have added the output and the code of what i have tried. i have used your method for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why there is any recommendation of Lambda here. What you need is simple: [S3 object created event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html#supported-notification-destinations) -> SQS and some job on your EC2 instance watching a [long polling queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html#sqs-long-polling).

Here is an example of such a python script. You need to sort out how the object key is encoded in the event, but it will be there. I haven't tested this, but it should be pretty close.

```
import boto3


def main() -> None:
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    sqs = boto3.client("sqs")
    while True:
        res = sqs.receive_message(
            QueueUrl="yourQueue",
            WaitTimeSeconds=20,
        )
        for msg in res.get("Messages", []):
            s3.download_file("yourBucket", msg["key"], "local/file/path")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I have added the method i have tried so far. Please see it and let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: You are going wrong, I believe, by involving a lambda at all. You don't need it or to involve ssm. Simply set your bucket to post object created events to an SQS queue with long polling as mentioned above. Then run a script on your ec2 instance that receives from this queue. That message will have the new s3 key. It can just be a simply python program that reads from the queue in a `while true` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html), which react to a new file coming into the `s3` bucket.
The destinations supported by s3 event are `SNS`, `SQS` or `AWS lambda`.

You can directly use the lambda as destination as described by @Marcin

You can use SQS has queue with a lambda behind pulling from the queue. It allows you to have some capability like **dead letter queue**. You can then pull messages from the queue using different methods:

- AWS CLI
- AWS SDK

You can use SNS with different things behind (you can have many of these desinations in a row which symbolise the **fan-out pattern**:

- a SQS queue to manage the files
- an email to notify
- a lambda function
- ...

You can find more explication in ths article: https://aws.plainenglish.io/system-design-s3-events-to-lambda-vs-s3-events-to-sqs-sns-to-lambda-2d41477d1cc9